# Javascript changes attributes in all items in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm pretty depressed because of this crazy problem.
I have a difficult data structure composed of objects and arrays.
It looks like this:

```
Team{
    name: "name_of_team",
    players: [

        // PLAYER 1
        {
            id: 0,
            position: 0,
            track:[

                // POINT 1
                {
                    time: 0,
                    checked: false
                },

                // POINT 2
                {
                    time: 0,
                    checked: false
                },

                // POINT 3
                {
                    time: 0,
                    checked: false
                }
            ]
        },

        // PLAYER 2
        {
            id: 1,
            position: 0,
            track:[

                // POINT 1
                {
                    time: 0,
                    checked: false
                },

                // POINT 2
                {
                    time: 0,
                    checked: false
                },

                // POINT 3
                {
                    time: 0,
                    checked: false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I can track players. When one from team gets to point, its parameter checked changes to true and time saves the time of getting this zone.
My function looks like this:

```
var a = Team.players.findIndex(x => x.id === 0);
var position = Team.players[a].position;
Team.players[a].track[position].checked = true;
Team.players[a].track[position].time = new Date();
Team.players[a].position++;
```

When I check parameter "a" it's set to 0 (right value) and it all seems good.
But "checked" and "time" parameter changes also in the second object (id == 1) in this array.
Crazy thing is that "position" parameter is correctly incremented only in the right object (id == 0).
I tried to hard index the item in array like:

```
Team.players[0].track...
```

But it behaves the same.
Has anyone experienced something like this or any ideas how to avoid second object being modified together with first object.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: where is `position` defined ? Also there are no associative arrays in js so it would help if you provide a valid data example

Comment: Uhm, how do you initialize the Objects inside the track array.. this smells heavlily like you're having side-effects because the point object in the arrays is the same object

Comment: I'm sorry. That should be

position = Team.players[a].position;

Comment: `Player1` and `Player2` are supposed to be an index in an array. What are they?

Comment: Objects are copied into an array. I create a track array elsewhere and then I copy it to player.track. When players are from the same team then track array is copied to both player.trace parameters.

Comment: Yes. They are only indexed objects. So team.players if array of object where every player contains another array of object named track.

Comment: I bet when constructing the `team` object, you have simply copied the same `track` array over the `players` array through a `map` or something. They reference each other. Use a `track.slice()` when creating the individual `track` arrays per player.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
Team.players[a].position
```

is the position, then just use it.

```
var a = Team.players.findIndex(x => x.id === 0);
Team.players[a].track[Team.players[a].position].checked = true;
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Team.players[a].track[Team.players[a].position].time = new Date();
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Team.players[a].position++;
```

Comment: I already fixed the code. I've written it wrong so I apologize.
Could you please have a look at it now?